# Display Selected Related List in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, related-list

I have requirement to display only specific related list(License in this case) in VF. I tried using following code but no success. I am using apex:details to hide all related list and then apex:related list to show specific related list. I need to know 2 things:-
-- Why this code is not working ?
-- Is there a better way to approach this problem ?

Also, attached picture of license object Api name.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" controller="FulfillmentRequestListViewPdfExtension" action="{!updateDistributionStatus}">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @media print {
                html, body {
                    height: 99%;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <apex:repeat value="{!frs}" var="fr" id="theRepeat">
            <apex:detail subject="{!fr}" id="theValue" relatedList="False" />
            
             <apex:relatedList list="Licenses__r">
              <apex:facet name="header">License Details</apex:facet> 
             </apex:relatedList>
            
               <div style="page-break-after: always;" />
        </apex:repeat>
    </body>
</html>
```

</apex:page>

[image]

Comment: Adding the "why" it is not working would be helpful. Any error message? And you got to include the apex code as well.

Comment: It shows no error messages. It just shows the VF page without any related list. Apex(Controller) has nothing to do with related list. I am using apex to update few fields.

Comment: You mentioned that you attached a picture but I can't see any.

Comment: Edited to add again.

Comment: I don't think `apex:detail` and `apex:relatedList` are to be put inside an `apex:repeat`

Comment: Why ? apex:detail is working fine when inside apex: repeat